# Referencing line numbers in an algorithm using autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmic, autoref

What is the autoref command to reference a line number of an algorithm? I tried to define `stepautorefname`, `linenoautorefname` and `alglinenoautorefname` commands as shown below but they don't work like the `algorithmautorefname` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage[hidelinks,
            colorlinks  = true,
            linkcolor   = blue,
            urlcolor    = blue,
            citecolor   = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}


\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\stepautorefname}{Step}
\newcommand{\linenoautorefname}{Line}
\newcommand{\alglinenoautorefname}{ALine}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm} \label{alg:A}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE A
\STATE B
\STATE C
\STATE D \label{step:A4}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


In \autoref{step:A4} of \autoref{alg:A}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation log already gives a useful hint:

> Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `ALC@unique' on input line 32.

So the command name prefix should be `ALC@unique`. We then only need to make sure the `@` character is allowed in command names and can define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ALC@uniqueautorefname}{Line}
\makeatother
```

which yields the desired result.

[image]

Comment: In some versions of `algorithm2e` the relevant command is `\AlgoLineautorefname` (thus the `\makeat` commands are unnecessary).  For future readers: if neither the answer above nor this comment help you, I recommend looking at your local `algorithm2e.sty` file.